# Recording and storing selenium IDE random values

Tags: automation, selenium-ide

I need to extract with selenium IDE a random value that generates always after login again into the app. How can I extract the new value when the page is loaded again?

ex:

Logout button:

```
id=ext-gen123 Logout
```

That ID is always different when I logout and login again.. So as you all can see, it's kind of weird when I ran the test cases again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there part of the string that's always the same?

```
xpath=//a[matches(@id,'ext-gen.*')]
```

See if you can consistently select it with that.

then use the storeAttribute command

```
storeAttribute | xpath=//a[matches(@id,'ext-gen.*')]@id | genIdVarName
```

You could add a class to the login element to make it easier to select.

Then you can use javascript if you want just part of the id string

some thing like

```
storeEval | storedVars['genIdVarName'].replace("ext-gen", "") | genNumberVarName
```

If this isn't what you want please add more detail to your question.